# Why is the last element in this array being converted to a reference? (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I am attempting to trim each string in an array of strings with the code below.  However, after executing this function, the *last* element in the array becomes a reference (note the '&' symbol preceding element #3 in the var_dump).  Why does this happen?  is it a bug or a PEBKAC?

```
$x = [" ABC ", "DEF  ", "   GHI", "JKL "];

// Trim all
foreach ($radio_types as &$r)
{
    $r = trim($r);
}

var_dump($x);

// Outputs this:
// array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "ABC" [1]=> string(3) "DEF" [2]=> string(3) "GHI" [3]=> &string(3) "JKL" }
```

Comment: it's because `$r` is still a reference to the last element, one should explicitly unset it after the `foreach` loop with `unset($r)` to avoid unexpected surprises... - see the Warning section in http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: OK I do see what you mean.  If I unset it, then everything works normally.  But that's completely maddening.  I would expect $r to hold a reference to the last array element, but I guess I was expecting $r to go out of scope outside the foreach loop, and not to affect the actual array.  Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: PHP scope  is within the function, not within control structures

Comment: @MarkBaker yep I had forgotten that.  Thx.